# remove all objects from scrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I remove all objects from a UIScrollView (completely clear the scroll view, no matter what is allocated inside):

I tried this but it does not work:

```
for (UIView *subview in scroll1.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove subviews from scrollview?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310723/how-to-remove-subviews-from-scrollview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried the code posted in the answer to this post ?

[Remove all the subviews from a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102362/remove-all-the-subviews-from-a-uiscrollview)

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, this worked: [scrollView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];