# What is the swift equivalent of makeObjectsPerformSelector?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

In Objective-C I'm using this code to remove any sub-views:

```
[self.view.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

But how to use it in swift? I saw [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/makeObjectsPerformSelector:) to use that method in swift

```
func makeObjectsPerformSelector(_ aSelector: Selector)
```

but when I try it, I get an error: `'AnyObject[]' does not have a member named 'makeObjectsPerformSelector'`

Are there any ways to remove sub-views in swift?

Comment: `(view.subviews as NSArray).enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ (view, index, stop) in
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        })`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

### UPDATE

I’m revisiting this answer 10 years later because there’s no good reason to use `forEach` instead of a `for` loop:

```
for subview in view.subviews {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

It’s worth noting that Ben Cohen, of the Swift Core Team and the Swift Language Steering Group, [strongly dislikes `forEach` for most situations](https://forums.swift.org/t/do-we-want-foreach/56929/2), so I’m not the only one giving this advice.

### ORIGINAL

Use `forEach`:

```
self.view.subviews.forEach { subview in
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Or like this:

```
view.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: ah, I didn't realize I read the documentation about NSArray and not Array in swift. thank you very much

Comment: Hmm... The second version (using `map`) crashes for me.  I haven't figured out why yet.  But the first version (using a cast) works, so just use that. ;^)

Comment: Map is a piece of cake!

Comment: I think the map() variant is a nice idea but won't fly - at least for NSArray's. Map has to return a value (it maps the value of a collection to another value). If the function you are calling is void (like removeFromSuperview()) - what is the resulting array to contain? (empty tuple 'object'?) This might work but is ugly: .map { e -> String in e.removeFromSuperview(); return "" }

Comment: map is used to construct a new array from an old array, so the block is suppose to return a value used for the new array. There doesn't seem to be a make objects perform equivalent, you can just use 'for obj in array {...}', also its probable not safe to modify an array while enumerating over it like that.

Comment: and the mapping crashes swift every time *sigh*. I had to bridge to a NSArray >.<

Comment: As of beta 5, `makeObjectsPerformSelector` joins the other `performSelector`-based API as being unavailable to Swift. Use a `for`-`in` loop instead: `for subview in view.subviews { subview.removeFromSuperview() }` Or, if you must, one of the functional-programming-style constructs (`map`, `filter`, `find`) -- but be aware that many consider it bad style to use those for nonfunctional work (i.e. work that has side effects).

Comment: As of Swift 2.0, `forEach` is provided natively. E.g. `view.subviews.forEach {$0.removeFromSuperview()}`

Answer (score 1):

As of Xcode 7, the full family of performSelector methods are available in Swift, including `makeObjectsPerformSelector()` for `NSArray`.

Answer (score 0):

It only works on NSArray and NSMutableArray objects.

This will work:

```
let ar: NSArray = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
ar.makeObjectsPerformSelector("someSelector")
```

Note that if you have an `Array<AnyObject>` you can freely convert to `NSArray` and vise versa.

```
let anNSArray: NSArray = anArrayOfAnyObject
anNSArray.makeObjectsPerformSelector( "someSelector")
```

Comment: question isn't asking how to do it with NSArray. It's asking, what is the Swift equivalent?