# bridgeToObjectiveC and makeObjectsPerformSelector in Swift beta 5

Tags: objective-c, swift

I had this code with a completion handler working in Xcode 6 beta 4 that no longer works in Xcode 6 beta 5.

```
dropsToRemove.bridgeToObjectiveC().makeObjectsPerformSelector("removeFromSuperview")
```

Full method...

```
func animateRemovingDrops(dropsToRemove: [UIView]) {
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0,
        animations: {
            for dropView in dropsToRemove {
                let x = CGFloat(UInt(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt(self.gameView.bounds.size.width) * 5)))) - self.gameView.bounds.size.width * 2
                let y = self.gameView.bounds.size.height
                dropView.center = CGPointMake(x, -y)
        }}, completion: { finished in
                dropsToRemove.bridgeToObjectiveC().makeObjectsPerformSelector("removeFromSuperview")
        })
}
```

The error is '[UIView]' does not have a member named 'bridgeToObjectiveC'

Note that the CGFloat and Uint casting in the method is for a beta 4 workaround, I just haven't updated that part yet. That issue is covered at:
[‘CGFloat’ is not convertible to ‘UInt8' and other CGFloat issues with Swift and Xcode 6 beta 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873219/cgfloat-is-not-convertible-to-uint8-and-other-cgfloat-issues-with-swift-and)

I thought the solution for dealing with the completion handler might be to treat the array as an NSArray as detailed in:
[What is the swift equivalent of makeObjectsPerformSelector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446372/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-makeobjectsperformselector)

```
(dropsToRemove as NSArray).makeObjectsPerformSelector("removeFromSuperview")
```

However, assuming I got the syntax right, simply results in another error 'makeObjectsPerformSelector' is unavailable: 'performSelector' methods are unavailable

Is this a new Swift bug, or something I'm missing in the release notes?

Comment: It's possible they just added it to the banned list. `dropsToRemove.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }` is pretty short.

Comment: @BrianNickel, it is a dangerous precedence to use map to produce side effects. That is not the purpose of map.

Comment: @drewag Fair enough point: `for drop in dropsToRemove { drop.removeFromSuperview() }` is still much shorter than the bridging code.

Comment: @BrianNickel, plus that is type safe :)

Comment: Thanks @BrianNickel. Should that be posted as an Answer? I'm always happy to see a better way that using bridging and selectors...

Comment: @kasplat, and otherwise, it seems pretty clear that `performSelector` and all of its similar methods have been deprecated in beta 5. I didn't see any reference to it in the release notes but it doesn't seem like a bug.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `bridgeToObjectiveC` and `bridgeFromObjectiveC` functions are not available in Xcode 6.0 beta 5. Instead, cast to/from the appropriate Foundation type when you need to use that type's API on a Swift object. For example:

```
var arr = ["One", "Two"]
(arr as NSArray).indexOfObject("One")
```

Apple has warned against (or explicitly made unavailable) using `performSelector` and related methods since the first Swift beta. Presumably any such API that were still available before beta 5 were unintentionally so.

As [the question you cited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24446372/what-is-the-swift-equivalent-of-makeobjectsperformselector) notes, you can use `map` to call a function/method on every element of an array. You can also use `filter`, `find` or a `for`-`in` loop, or after casting to `NSArray`, one of the `enumerateObjects` methods. Note that many consider it bad style to use the [functional-programming](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) constructs (`map`, `filter`, `reduce`, `find`) for tasks that aren't "functional" -- that is, to run code that has [side effects](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). So a `for`-`in` loop might be the cleanest way to do what you're after.

Comment: Thanks @rickster. I also had to replace code like `let chosenViewIndex = cardButtons.bridgeToObjectiveC().indexOfObject(sender.view as PlayingCardView)` with `let chosenViewIndex = find(cardButtons, sender.view as PlayingCardView)!` which is clearer, but I hadn't used earlier due to problems with the optional result of find()

Comment: @rickster Great answer!`to run code that has side effects` can you please explain the side effects or provide some link about that

Comment: Added some Wikipedia links to explain those terms.

Answer (score 1):

Someone from Apple has stated that those `bridgeToObjectiveC` and `bridgeFromObjectiveC` functions are meant as private functions, i.e. for Apple internal use only, and that they would go away.

I will try to find the link to that statement in the developer forums, if you happen to be in the developer program.