# bridgeToObjectiveC not available on Swift Beta 5

Tags: swift, ios8

I'm writing an app that uses bridgeToObjectiveC() on a String object. Since Beta 5 this is no longer available.

I'm trying to do this:

```
self.myList.filter{($0 as MyClass).name.bridgeToObjectiveC().localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchText)}
```

Which gives me the error:

```
'String' does not have a member named 'bridgeToObjectiveC'
```

What is the equivalent code in Beta 5?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bridgeToObjectiveC and makeObjectsPerformSelector in Swift beta 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126188/bridgetoobjectivec-and-makeobjectsperformselector-in-swift-beta-5)

Comment: @MartinR He's talking about arrays, I'm talking about strings. No?

Comment: The problem is the same (bridgeToObjectiveC not available anymore) and the solution is the same ("... Instead, cast to/from the appropriate Foundation type").

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `as` to cast to `NSString` for the same effect:

```
("string" as NSString).localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("other string")
```

Or like this with optional chaining:

```
("string" as NSString?)?.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare("other string")
```

Answer (score 3):

try

`_bridgeToObjectiveC()`

instead of

`bridgeToObjectiveC()`

as follows:

```
self.myList.filter{($0 as MyClass).name._bridgeToObjectiveC().localizedCaseInsensitiveContainsString(searchText)}
```

Comment: Swift 2.0 fix this problem. And this behaviour is working.                                                                 var yearlyWorkDays = workDaysTxt.text._bridgeToObjectiveC().float