# bridgeToObjectiveC() not available for Array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know it's not available since Xcode-beta 5. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25126188/bridgetoobjectivec-and-makeobjectsperformselector-in-swift-beta-5) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131122/bridgetoobjectivec-not-available-on-swift-beta-5).

I have this source which is an extension for Array:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(object:AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return false
        }

        let array: NSArray = self.bridgeToObjectiveC();

       return array.containsObject(object)
    }
}
```

I modified it:

```
extension Array {
    func contains(object:AnyObject!) -> Bool {
        if(self.isEmpty) {
            return false
        }

        return (self as NSArray).containsObject(object);
    }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The error message is:

> Cannot convert the expression's type 'AnyObject!' to type 'NSArray'

What should I do? Thanks

Comment: Note that `Array` is not an object thus not an `AnyObject` but it is an `Any`.

Comment: Array is not an object?

Comment: Array is a struct as is String and Dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Swift has a 'find' function that you can use to see if an element is in an array or not:

```
find(array,element):C.Index?
```

It will return `nil` if the item is not found. You should probably use this instead of contains.