# Xcode 7 warning: Result of call to 'map' is unused

Tags: swift, dictionary, functional-programming, warnings, xcode7

I'd like to remove all subviews of my label like so:

```
label.subviews.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

This used to work in Xcode 6. But in Xcode 7 I get the following warning:

*Result of call to 'map' is unused*

This warning doesn't make sense. How can I suppress it?

**UPDATE:** I got this to work by doing the following, however, I'd like to keep a functional programming style and stick with map { }. This should also work.

```
label.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

Comment: You could use the foreach extension described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24446427/730701).

Comment: Thanks! However, I'd still like to have map { } work in order to maintain functional programming style.

Comment: @Daniel `forEach` has functional programming style as well.

Comment: @DánielNagy: I would not consider it a duplicate of *that* question. That question is about a different error message (caused by a typo), this question is about a warning (unused result). Even if the same answer applies, the questions are different.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel Nagy, that is exactly the response (with explanation!) I was looking for. It's not exactly the same, but answered my question. Koszi

Comment: @Daniel I'm glad I could help! Szívesen :)

Comment: You are trying to use map as a general purpose looping construct which is not the idea of map. In FP map means convert a set of value to other set of values which is not what your requirement of "removing a set of subviews" is about

Comment: @Ankur, you are converting. You can think of it as converting to nil. (Or using a method to convert each element, in this case remove(), which does something, somehow. It happens to remove, but map doesn't care about that.) I don't think that's the problem. The problem is that the list is immutable and map { } simply creates a new list as opposed to modifying the actual label.subviews list.

Comment: @Daniel: That something that you are doing in the map is not referential transparent though so it is not really a FP function

Comment: @Daniel I don't see how you can both want to "keep a functional programming style" and consider the immutability a problem. `map` is simply the wrong tool for the job here, and `forEach` was created exactly for this purpose.

Comment: _ = label.subviews.map { $0.removeFromSuperview() }