# How can I execute the same function for all objects of a collection in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a collection say Array that contains objects that implement this protocol

```
protocol Observer {
    func update(message: String)
}
let observers = [Observer]()
... 
// usually I use this loop to tell all observers 
for observer in observers {
    observer.update(message: "updated")
}
```

What I want here is to do something like that:

```
observers.executeForAll{$0.update(message:"updated")}
```

I know this exists in other programming languages, but can this be done in swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
observers.forEach { $0.update(message: "updated") }
```

Comment: Why did you reopen the question? This is a duplicate. Your solution is identical to the one in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24446427/1187415

Comment: This should be the answer you wanted @KhaledAnnajar

Comment: @MartinR this isn't a duplicate because the question is actually really different

Comment: @MartinR this isn't a direct duplicate of the question even with another title , plus if you look for duplicates can you close for example delegate pattern questions which has dozens of similar answers daily and for sure you see them ?

Comment: @MartinR I just could not find the question you are pointing to before creating my question.