# Remove subviews from ScrollView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I use a for-loop to create labels and buttons inside my scrollView.
Is it possible to remove all objects indside my scrollView? (I would like to update it with new content)

```
for peop in personArray{

        scrollView.clearContent ??????


        // Name label
        var label: UILabel = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRectMake(8, CGFloat(nameHeight), 183, 21)
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textColor =  UIColor(red: 90/255.0, green: 187/255.0, blue: 206/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        label.font = UIFont (name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 14)
        label.text = " \(peop.getName()) - \(sex)"
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)


        //Delete button
        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
        button.tag = playerId
        button.frame = CGRectMake(199, CGFloat(nameHeight), 37, 21)
        button.backgroundColor = colorWheel.colorsArray[7]
        button.setTitle("Slet", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "delAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(button)
        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 14)


        scrollHeight = scrollHeight + 29
        nameHeight = nameHeight + 29
        playerId++
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 20.0, height: CGFloat(nameHeight))
}

func delAction(sender: UIButton!){
    personArray.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    updatePeople()
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
let subViews = self.scrollView.subviews
for subview in subViews{
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) i was looking for removeFromSuperview()! Works like a charm!

Comment: This worked for me, if looking  to only remove last added subview:
`let subViews = self.view.subviews`
`subViews.last?.removeFromSuperview()`

Answer (score 28):

One line solution, use

```
scrollView.subviews.forEach({ $0.removeFromSuperview() })
```

**UPDATED**

For removing only specific kind of view, say `UIButton` use

```
scrollView.subviews.forEach ({ ($0 as? UIButton)?.removeFromSuperview() })
```

Comment: How could i judge a kind of class (like: UIButton) to delete in this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with block approach,

```
let views: NSArray = scroller.subviews

// 3 - remove all subviews
views.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock {
(object: AnyObject!, idx: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
  object.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

****Swift 5.9****

We can use below code if we want to remove specific object otherwise we can directly use `currentView.removeFromSuperview()`

```
for currentView in scrollView.subviews where currentView is UIButton {
  currentView.removeFromSuperview()
}
```